# get_success_url produce "None" at the end of URL

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

I have been trying to use "UpdateView" in django generic views. What I am trying to achieve is to return to the same "UpdateView" page.
My codes are as follows:
My urls

```
#urls.py    
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^code/(?P<pk>\d+)/update/', CodeUpdate.as_view(model=Code, template_name='code_update.html'),name='update',),
    )
```

my views

```
#views.py
class CodeUpdate(UpdateView):
    def get_success_url(self):
        pass
```

After clicking the update button the I expected the destination to be

> /code/18/update/

however it turns out to be

> /code/18/update/None

How do I remove "None" at the end? Thanks.

Now if I do this:

```
#views.py
class CodeUpdate(UpdateView):
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('update')
```

I will get this error.

> Reverse for 'update' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'/code/(?P\d+)/update/']

How can I pass the 'pk' value as the argument in the reverse function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once update is successful, it will redirect to url returned by `get_success_url()`. As you are not returning anything in that function, you are redirected to `.../update/None`.

Either return appropriate url from that method or remove that method for default behavior.

Comment: You're right on the cause. The default behavior is to redirect to the result of the `get_absolute_url` method of the updated object, which probably isn't what the OP is looking for. To redirect to the update view of the object again, give the URL pattern a name. Then use `reverse` to look up the URL for it and return it from `get_success_url`.

Comment: If `success_url` is `None` then `get_absolute_url` will be called.

Comment: Hi @PeterDeGlopper . I was trying to get object.id as the argument for the reverse function. It works if I hard code it into the `reverse('update',args=(11,))`, how can I do it dynamically. Thanks.

Comment: `UpdateView` saves the object you're updating as `self.object`, so `reverse('update', args=(self.object.id))` should do it.